# Connecting to ecostream.tv via JSoup

Tags: java, http, stream

Hey Guys i hope you'r able to help me :D
Im currently programming an downloader for some streamwebsites but i got a problem with this hoster.
My current code when trying to read out the link to "http://www.ecostream.tv/stream/f5c2e9da297ee26e77e6005ee3266b39.html":

```
            Document doc = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Postpage: "+postpage);
        System.out.println("id: "+newid);
        System.out.println("temp: "+tmp);
        System.out.println("superslots: "+superslots);

        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ecostream.tv"+postpage+"/id="+newid+"&tpm="+tmp+superslots)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0")
                .header("Accept","application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01")
                .header("Accept-Language","de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3")
                .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
                .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                .header("Referer", url)
                //.timeout(3000)
                .post();

        System.out.println(doc.html());

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("\"url\":\"(/[^<>\"]*?)\"");
    Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(doc.html());
    String finallink = null;
    if(m3.find()){
        finallink = m3.group(1);
    }

    return finallink;
```

Gave me :

```
Postpage: /xhr/videos/wOIriO01
id: f5c2e9da297ee26e77e6005ee3266b39
temp: IdOxkBKqRyW
superslots: Hwh7_kuOyGg

org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404,   URL=http://www.ecostream.tv/xhr/videos/wOIriO01  /id=f5c2e9da297ee26e77e6005ee3266b39&tpm=IdOxkBKqRyWHwh7_kuOyGg
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:459)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:170)
at Hoster.EcoStream.getdownloadlink(EcoStream.java:117)
at Main.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Hoster.EcoStream.getdownloadlink(EcoStream.java:142)
at Main.Main.main(Main.java:30)
```

So what am i doing wrong the neat sniffing tool HTTPFox got me :

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150601/48a9d95m.png

Thats my targetlink i wanna to read out.

Comment: I suspect that of these long strings in the URL is generated using the cookies or POST that your browsers sends, so that this is not persistent link. I guess you have to add cookies from your browser or query some more URLs before you can download the content.

Comment: any idea how to do that ? to use the cookies ? and btw the thinks like Postpage,id,temp and superslots are always the same for this file.

Comment: Ok you are right stealing the cookie from my browser solved the problem. I used this :                                                    .header("Cookie", "eco=BAh7B0kiDHRocnVwdXQGOgZFRkkiKTFiOTM3NjBlLWVlMGMtNTA4MC1iYTMz%250ALTU1NDI0NTI2MDZjNwY7AFRJIglwYXNzBjsARkkiDnN1cGVycGFzcwY7AEY%253D--bd90c2c60f7cf743c560753bfe1251c57c1a0348; __utma=58297534.350315215.1433019075.1433169369.1433172197.5; __utmz=58297534.1433172197.5.4.utmcsr=bs.to|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/serie/Criminal-Minds/1/21-Alte-Freunde/Ecostream-1; cs=1; __utmc=58297534; __utmb=58297534.2.10.1433172197; __utmt=1")

Comment: After try and error this is the important line in the cookie : eco=BAh7B0kiDHRocnVwdXQGOgZFRkkiKTFiOTM3NjBlLWVlMGMtNTA4MC1iYTMz%250ALTU1NDI0NTI2MDZjNwY7AFRJIglwYXNzBjsARkkiDnN1cGVycGFzcwY7AEY%253D--bd90c2c60f7cf743c560753bfe1251c57c1a0348)